# MySQL: Which data type can handle special character?

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL table, and in message field I want to store encrypted data. Encrypted data looks like

```
�O-�H,,E%P!�O-�H-!E%!P!�O-�H,E%�P!�O-�H,,E$�P"�O-!H,E%P!�O-H+�E%P"
```

Hence, I cannot store such characters in message either I did utf_general_ci or blog.

Please help me to figure out which datatype can store such characters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this URL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

"Many encryption and compression functions return strings for which the result might contain arbitrary byte values. **If you want to store these results, use a column with a VARBINARY or BLOB binary string data type**. This will avoid potential problems with trailing space removal or character set conversion that would change data values, such as may occur if you use a nonbinary string data type (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT)."

Comment: I cannot store either with your answer. I tried varbinary as well.

Comment: What mysql error message do you get storing this value?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `TEST1` (
  `DATA` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 <br/> `insert into TEST1 VALUES ('\�O-�H,,E%P!�O-�H-!E%!P!�O-�H,E%�P!�O-�H,,E$�P\"�O-!H,E%P!�O-H+�E%P"');`

Comment: If output from encryption returns special characters, like single quote (') or double quote ("), your insert or update statement will fail. If you execute inserts or updates inside any application, you can encode value using for example  base64 encoding, and store the encoded value int mysql field.